# Limiting data access in SSRS Report Builder 3.0

Tags: sql-server, database, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I have made a shared data source using Oracle but I do not want other SSRS users to create a new data set. I want the users to use only my shared data set.

I want to disable "Use a data set embedded in my report" radio button in report builder.

Can it be done?

Comment: I don't think you can do this.

Comment: Edited for grammar and clarity